# Screen recorders force close in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, screen

I tried screen recording with Kazam and when I started the recording it forced closed, so I tried with another one, called simple-screen-recorder and the same thing happened, once I launched the recording.

Thats what I got in terminal:

```
==================== SSR started ====================   
SimpleScreenRecorder 0.2.2
Compiled with GCC 4.8.2
Qt: header 4.8.6, lib 4.8.6
libavformat: header 54.20.3, lib 54.63.104
libavcodec: header 54.35.0, lib 54.92.100
libavutil: header 52.3.0, lib 52.18.100
libswscale: header 2.1.1, lib 2.2.100
[DetectCPUFeatures] CPU features: mmx sse sse2 sse3 ssse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 avx avx2 bmi1 bmi2
[PageRecord::StartPage] Starting page ...
[PageRecord::StartPage] Started page.
[PageRecord::StopPage] Stopping page ...
[PageRecord::StopPage] Stopped page.
[PageRecord::StartPage] Starting page ...
[PageRecord::StartPage] Started page.
[PageRecord::StartOutput] Starting output ...
[Muxer::Init] Using format matroska (Matroska).
[BaseEncoder::CreateCodec] Using codec libx264 (libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10).
[libx264 @ 0x25be000] using SAR=1/1
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any help? --Thanks.

Comment: - Start one from command line and see if it throws any errors. - Insert error message into google :)

Comment: Can you please run these applications through a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and post back any error messages (Ctrl+Shift+C to copy from terminal)

Comment: thats what i got down

Answer (score 0):

**Correction:**

While the solution I posted earlier did indeed solve the problem for me, it is the incorrect method for solving this issue.

SSR makes use of libav, not ffmpeg. You will need to uninstall the ffmpeg version you have on your system. Please disregard my solution below.

**Incorrect solution:**

I had this issue with SimpleScreenRecorder 0.2.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit as well. It would seem that FFMPEG/avconv will seg fault when trying to identify your CPU capabilities (according to the developer of SSR).

Here is a quick fix, that should help you. I did this, and it allows me to use SSR with MP4 and H.264 again. Open a new Terminal, and enter the following commands and hit Enter for each (it's just two commands):

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jon-severinsson/ffmpeg
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

What this does, is that it adds a PPA that contains a newer version of FFMPEG/avconv maintained by Jon Severinsson. The second command then checks for updates, finds them and installs them (in this case, it finds the new FFMPEG/avconv).

There you go! You should now be able to record with SSR again. I hope this helps you :)

**Further information:**

This problem only seems to affect Intel CPUs, and even then I'm not sure how many are affected. My Intel i7-4770 seg faults with FFMPEG 1.2.5-1, but my AMD 965 x4 does not with the same FFMPEG.

By default, Ubuntu 14.04 comes with FFMPEG 7:1.2.5-1. The PPA will bump this to 7:1.2.6-1 at the time of this writing.

If this does not solve it for you, then I recommend you alert the developer of SSR on his GitHub page here: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues?state=open

I opened an issue for this, and I came to this solution thanks to his help. This is the related issue we both have: https://github.com/MaartenBaert/ssr/issues/179